# Problems with losing MathJax formatting previews while creating question or answer

Tags: bug, mathjax, formatting, markdown-preview

I've tried searching the site, but couldn't find anything that answers my question.

Whenever I'm creating a new question or answer and I'm taking a while to type it all out since I'm still learning the MathJax system, very frequently the preview with all my nice MathJax formatting shows all the base code. Since I'm still learning MathJax, I really need to use the preview to see if it will render what I want it to look like. Every time this happens, I end up having to copy everything I typed, discard the question, then create a new question and paste the text, which will then render all the formatting. I usually have to do this about 5 times for each question or answer I create.

What would be causing this, and how can I fix it? Also, is there somewhere I can compose my question or answer and test the MathJax formatting? Preferably an offline program or something, to minimize any possibility that something about my browser is interfering with the previews on here.

Comment: Yes, in recent time I am also facing the same problem. I use Windows 10 and google chrome latest version, I always keep it updated. But, when I copy all my base codes as well as the whole answer and then refresh the page. Then paste the copied answer, it shows the correct form.

Comment: I am on Windows 10 with Google Chrome as well.

Comment: Ok, then try refreshing the page, just `ctrl+R`. And before this don't forget to copy the contents.

Comment: Workaround: use robjohn's [bookmarks](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html), in particular Rendering Off/On to give the system a hand remembering to render. It's amazing how many times I've recommended those; they're so helpful!

Comment: I've only been using MSE with Windows 7 and 8.1. Chrome works fine (but sometimes MathJax doesn't work - this probably occurs once every two weeks or so). But with IE11, I have consistent problems on MSE with respect to MathJax. I don't recommend IE11.

Comment: Re: *Also, is there somewhere I can compose my question or answer and test the MathJax formatting?* See [MathJax: better way to prepare a Math.StackExchange question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4735/mathjax-better-way-to-prepare-a-math-stackexchange-question) and other posts [linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4735). Maybe also other posts tagged [mathjax+editor](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax+editor) can be interesting for you.

Comment: This looks like it might be the same issue as described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275997/mathjax-preview-bug-seems-to-be-neglected), with instructions for reproducing the issue.  I'm looking into it.

Comment: See my [post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22984/mathjax-editing-preview-improvements-userscript) that includes a user-script that should work around this problem until the editing code can be updated.